# Считывание файла из буфера обмена с Clipboard API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование, typescript, frontend

Пытаюсь считать файл из буфера обмена с помощью Clipboard API.

```
const clipboard = await window.navigator.clipboard.read();
console.debug(clipboard);
```

Браузер выдаёт ошибку при выполнении данного кода:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: No valid data on clipboard.
```

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы данная ошибка не возникала и можно было получать файлы из буфера обмена?